# Recover an App Service from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

yesterday I deleted the wrong web app from my azure's account. I tried to follow steps here found on google but this assume's there was a backup made. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-restore/ is there a way to recover a deleted web app without having a backup of it?

Comment: Since you didn't have any backups via App Service backup: Did you lose code, or did you lose data stored locally within your web app? If it's code, you can just redeploy from your repository. If it's data in a database service (e.g. SQL Database) or azure storage, it should all still be there. If it was stored locally (e.g. SQLite), there's really nothing you can do, short of contacting support.

Comment: please contact Azure Support to recover your site. If i am not wrong, as long as your site was running during the past 14 days. Azure should keep a snapshot of your site somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to recover an app service without having a backup of it, recently Microsoft released a new preview feature to allow you to restore deleted apps, please use the following commands:

To get if the app service is available to restore: [Get-AzureRmDeletedWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/get-azurermdeletedwebapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-6.9.0)

> Get-AzureRmDeletedWebApp -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-WestUS" -Name
>   "ContosoSite"

To restore it: [Restore-AzureRmDeletedWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/restore-azurermdeletedwebapp?view=azurermps-6.13.0&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-6.9.0)

> Restore-AzureRmDeletedWebApp -ResourceGroupName Default-Web-WestUS -Name ContosoApp -TargetAppServicePlanName ContosoPlan

Answer (score 0):

The latest powershell commands to restore an app are Get-AzDeletedWebApp and Restore-AzDeletedWebApp. This article ([How to restore a deleted Azure Web App](https://ruslany.net/2019/06/how-to-restore-a-deleted-azure-web-app/)) explains how to use them.